# Fill HTML5 arc with a picture - HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a HTML5 Canvas ([***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ecv8de4L/)) that looks like: [image]

I am creating the balls by the following method:

```
function createball(x,y,r,color){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();

}
```

How can I fill the ball with image? I mean a image that might have patters or some natural color?

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Nope. My Question is straight forward about a ball only. Just to fill image to a ball

Comment: @benjour, Actually Yep. You could create a pattern and set the ball's `fillStyle` to that pattern--just like in the duplicate answer that Ken references. ;-)

Comment: @markE Maybe I did not understand what you mean, mind posting an answer?

Comment: @benjour. Sure...done. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a pattern and set the ball's fillStyle to that pattern

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/checkerboard.jpg";
function start(){
  var pattern=ctx.createPattern(img,'repeat');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50,50,15,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=pattern;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Source Image:</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/checkerboard.jpg'>
<h4>Fill Circle with pattern made from source image</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=100 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. One more, can this be done with sprites?

Comment: Do you mean cut individual sprites from a spritesheet? Sure, its a bit more complicated. (1) create an in-memory canvas (`document.createElement`) the size of your sprite, (2) use the clipping version of `drawImage` to draw the desired sprite to the in-memory canvas, (3) use the in-memory canvas as the image source to `createPattern`...and then you have a sprite-pattern cut from a spritesheet! Good luck with your project!